# Request/response "language" design when using Web Sockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io with nodejs on the server side to provide two-way communication between my web application and the server.

I am using the socket.io API to issue commands and receive responses, but I am not sure if there is a more methodical way of defining a "language" for sending commands to the server and receiving results from it.

For sending commands to the server, I am emitting events from the web application like the following (I am using pseudo code below):

```
socket.emit('commandRequest', {
                msg_id: '...'
                username: '...',
                command: '...'                    
});
```

The server evaluates the command and emits responses like the following:

```
socket.on('commandRequest', (data) => {
    // parse and execute data.command

    socket.emit('commandResponse', {
        msg_id: data.msg_id,
        username: data.username,
        response: ...,
        error: ...
    });
})
```

Finally, the web application is listening to responses from the server and it updates the app content accordingly:

```
socket.on('commandResponse', (data) => {
    if (data.error) {
        ...
    } else {
        // interpret data.response
    }
})
```

So I am using the commandRequest/commandResponse event naming paradigm and the event data structure has corresponding `{command: ...}` and `{response: ...}` properties.

Is there a more formal way of defining a request/response "language" that can be used for more complex client/server interactions? Something similar to what REST APIs achieve with HTTP request, but using web sockets?

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into [Primus](https://github.com/primus/primus) and its [Responder](https://github.com/swissmanu/primus-responder) plugin as described in this blog post: [Request-Response Oriented Websockets](http://alabor.me/articles/request-response-oriented-websockets/)

An excerpt from the post:

> It allows to request the opposite peer for a response using a simple API known from other libraries.
>
> Primus Responder adds two things to Primus' core functionality:
>
> 1. A new event called `request` is emitted as soon as a peer requests a response.
> 2. The new method named `writeAndWait(data, fn)` writes data to a peer and runs given callback function as the peer sends its response.
>
> Primus Responder is available on the client too.